# Is this some sort of hacker attack?

Tags: php, hardening

I'm using a tool on my website that detects any error and sends me an email when a code error happens. Recently, I've received some requests not allowed on my IP **- not url -** where only GET is allowed.

The requests all come from the IP `173.187.177.22` and, besides happening once a minute or two, have a strange input. Here's a few examples of the input passed on three different requests:

```
array(1) {
  ["QqIKyIubMeV_mOiW6N7CL6c1rCSY9W1cSlveqfTb9P9cpfwTTOL1sOUdhvIphPNeVGdeKl9lhHf7ADk9gLNgePAZdO/ygtxofmT/sfbFyrBKzGvrWRVL6kT2zbkVrV1dOXIQkhDuUUpacUnKuaPkB78z85jmqjY1l7hXnLIONUtctt679mbW9KPHoq1ozFK6Ki1hfN9WnwnaN14akSGWZkDfoVDFdrneVf4JDOlfY3r78Gp39bueUaHn6aMEAGys3MEEjr4ghbHe0T6MURgQyHZHoV1olgRiAo5xRjChrhjD7w/pYaaNi0_6DKHMJBS7H9_bw8I/qaOoFy/EeO4G3QFiIlpcutIEf62YOwlk53MzuuLM5eje9I_TUXc9XmC/kU9EX2QDYYT9wGmg3w/7YJSOIIgi"]=>
  NULL
}
array(1) {
  ["RfZWlNmbZ3O21/tLFs9AFHaO5zr9g/FArn8djhJGYhqs32THrVCnqDI/xUAJcg0DGKi6a/FEz7PzB7GWu72B7uA3ZvdKfNUhSCZR39If6oOCATHN9VYgzYJQfDaPrcqJh3IBaHPcJSgUXsv_amGKAd6AJ675AtCvMfdYUQk5V/Pc1X2LR2M7uDfEW1Mv2S9mHSZSLYV_cDAJFOavCtxfyLQms3kOudm_arsbkn2kQbh1LvaC0iP0aDSfmmEmtFIX_rmMwSGFghPV1mZtELD6NEjuorMwix70CvGi/g27CRmU0qtuVwwlhf67Qi7cZBNCOzAb_mFMfUnp1E4kWhbvIpNyo_c0TuwM_BNRKm9UQc8rdWPk8CmN"]=>
  NULL
}
array(1) {
  ["RfFelN_ZbKsBnezpI20p0My0Rd7Gzx4bNeu9iTNNiizOsqFE_uCyvsWkg_zvep1KlWlp9fTNSImM9hitT/Zrs/UvxMgTp1llGwg1a3WinrqPXZSySmQkaU7WXXHHf/_sWk1OcEp6PfFXczId60vlvr9X7OTVlNDLW7oET38xmCV0Q7sL_s/iLlilTAHIh7ICTxqOTzO2ONFFpcqy/wD6Hw4TEFiS1g6APil_/aJkbd/My6ESB4jXehj3HhEbLUWVRsQlJa6cCVKJpwieEAiZCi/N2EgaEd3jxRdKrIA75VgVPteDdqaSnPUljHXerCMic2UzVfLqWvK4w8beTnoKnQacmJf8c6ANr8l3fU2pQn7zmqdzO/LL6MNsbVF0B0G9iFm0x9fO0cuN8MUW5IlI289ILTvpLpJL2Qg6QQ"]=>
  string(1) "="
}
```

Any suggestions on what I should put in place to prevent this kind of behavior? In the past I've blocked the IPs responsible for this from .htaccess, but ideally I don't want to continue blocking IPs manually since if it is some sort of attack it could bypass IP

Comment: how is this input strange? We have no idea how your code works so we do not understand in what way this input might be concerning (if at all)

Comment: the code is not meant to do POST requests on home page and, having 1'200 visitors everyday seems strange that only that IP gives error... it's just **very** suspicious

Comment: Did your server IP change recently or is the server new? Could this be a client of some other service trying to connect to a server that no longer exists on that IP?

Comment: There are tons of bots  scanning the whole internet and trying to exploit known vulnerabilities. Over time, you will be getting more and more of them, as your website becomes more visible in google.

Comment: That's my guess, but how should I counter this? I could turn off error notifications, but I prefer not to.
@schroeder nothing of what you suggested unfortunately. We operate in Italy and this is basically the only US IP we served recently.

Comment: Maybe add a generic POST handler that drops the connection? This way it wouldn't interfere with normal error handling. Alternatively a 404 is plenty valid.

Comment: I like your approach: I've decided to catch all MethodNotAllowedErrors on home page and `exit()` with a message, while logging a warning about this event. I'm not sure about a 404 page: after all it is an error.

Comment: Reading back through the HTTP spec 501 is the correct response.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to address unexpected and invalid inputs from web clients is to install a WAF (web application firewall). There are free and paid versions.

In this firewall, you configure the types of valid inputs and you can drop/reject/correct invalid inputs. Not only can this help with bots/hackers testing your app for weaknesses, but it can address things like SQLi, XSS, etc.

While a WAF can get complex fast (you can define valid inputs for each one of your functions, which is something to consider), you can also provide "broad stroke" protection and define that `POST`s are invalid, for instance.

Comment: I chose to `exit()` in case a method different from GET is used on home page. I guess it's in line with your answer, just really basic